# Loading valid CSON always returns [TypeError: undefined is not a function]

Tags: node.js, cson

I am using the exact CSON from the [official CSON docs](https://github.com/bevry/cson)

```
{
    # an array
    abc: [
        'a'
        'b'
        'c'
    ]

    # an object
    a:
        b: 'c'
}
```

Loading this file (saved in `test.cson`) always returns an error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var CSON = require('cson'),
  log = console.log.bind(console);

var config = CSON.parseFileSync('test.cson')
if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(config) === '[object Error]' ) {
  log('Error loading file', config)
  process.exit(1)
}

log('winning')
```

Running this always returns:

```
Error loading file [TypeError: undefined is not a function]
```

**How can I load a CSON file?**

Comment: @Sirko the `Object.prototype.toString.call` is returning `'[object Error]'` and thus logging that error. It's from the `parseFileSync` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was **running an unstable (0.11) version of node** - I'd switched to another machine where I was working on something which required generators. At the time of writing, CSON does not work on node 0.11.

Answer (score 2):

I copy/pasted your exact code and it's working perfectly in my system, and printing out `config` shows me the correct object. Some things for you:

1. (What I think it's most likely your mistake) Make sure you have installed the CSON library! In the folder of your script, run: 
   `npm install cson`
2. Check if the file `test.cson` exists and is readable.

If that doesn't help, you need to better understand where the issue is.
Before using the CSON library, try adding a `console.log(CSON)`. Before your "if", then, add a `console.log(config)`. What do you see?

Comment: Using `cson@1.6.1`. Running console.log(CSON) returns:
    { parseFile: [Function],
      parseFileSync: [Function]etc } so the module looks like it's loaded properly too. test.cson exists and is readable.

Comment: What are the permissions of test.cson? Also, is your terminal in the same folder as the script?

Comment: test.cson is world readable, test.js is in same folder as test.cson. Weird thing is I can get it to work on another box too...